# Laravel 6 - Phpspreadsheet reading file excel

Tags: php, laravel, spreadsheet

i'm trying to read excel file like this:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
 $spreadsheet = $spreadsheet->load(public_path("dispoP.xlsx"));
```

But i get this error:

```
 Argument 1 passed to PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx\Styles::__construct() must be an instance of SimpleXMLElement, bool given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/daniele_ecommerce/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php on line 567
```

**Version phpspreadsheet**

```
 "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9",
```

**PHP Version**

```
7.3.24
```

I saw in library package that this return "false" when instead should be instance SimpleXMLElement ?

```
$xmlStyles = simplexml_load_string(
                        $this->securityScanner->scan($this->getFromZipArchive($zip, "$dir/$xpath[Target]")),
                        'SimpleXMLElement',
                        Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions()
                    );
```

thank you! i lost my sunday with this error :)

Comment: Maybe something is corrupted in the xlsx file. Maybe it's a bug that's been corrected in current version of phpspreadsheet (1.16.1) which you should be able to get using the command `composer update phpoffice/phpspreadsheet`. I tried your code locally with a spreadsheet of my own and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight error in the call you mention, but I don't think it's that:

```
$this->securityScanner->scan($this->getFromZipArchive($zip, "$dir/$xpath[Target]")),
```

should be

```
$this->securityScanner->scan($this->getFromZipArchive($zip, "{$dir}/{$xpath['Target']}")),
```

The problem has to be indeed where you say.

The simplest thing to do would be to dump the argument to `simplexml_load_string()` or, possibly, the whole kerfuffle, mainly `$dir/$xpath[Target]`. You can open the XLSX file as a Zip (just change the extension to .zip) and verify whether the XML file inside is intact and valid.

If it is, this means that the "security Scanner" somehow renders it into something that `simplexml_load_string()` does not parse - maybe an empty string.

Comment: It looks weird, but the code is correct. (or at least that's how it still looks like in [current version](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php#L474) and it throws no errors)